# Is there a search engine that does not forward the query to Google?

Tags: privacy, google-search, search-engine, duckduckgo

**This is a search engine privacy question.**

Imagine a scenario where a person wants to check if some sensitive fact about him/her is easily found with a web based search engine. For example, let us say that someone named Malanchersky wanted to find out if his membership of the well known Falanchersky organisation was known. An easy solution would be to type in "Malanchersky Falanchersky" in Google and see if the results revealed anything.

He would now have his answer, but from my understanding of things, next time someone else types in "Malanchersky" in Google, then **Google will provide them with** the **hint** of "Falanchersky" which might cause this person to suspect the relationship. Does anyone know if a single search such as this will cause Google to use it as a hint and is there a way to avoid this?

Neither a private window nor a VPN would solve this problem and even DuckDuckGo forwards its queries to Google. Is there a privacy respecting search engine that does not forward queries to non privacy respecting search engines or is it possible to prevent DuckDuckGo from forwarding queries to other search engines?

Comment: "from my understanding of things, next time someone else types in "Malanchersky" in Google, then Google will provide them with the hint of "Falanchersky" which might cause this person to suspect the relationship" I'm unaware of this. A source will be needed to comprove it's not just an original hypotesis.

Comment: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/7368877?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwhere-autocomplete-predictions-come-from says that hints are (among other things) inspired by past searches.